# Optimize big MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I have MYISAM table with 60 000 000 rows. It has a lot of INSERTS and some SELECTS (not UPDATEs).

Executed INSERTs  blocks reads (its obviously).

I only read 1% of rows, other 99% rows will be never reads.

I want optimize this. I think is good way to create duplicate table only for SELECTs with popular rows.

Is any ready solution for this? I'm working at PHP+MySQL.

Comment: post table schema, use indexes for fast searching

Comment: If you have an auto_increment primary key so that INSERTs all go to the end of the table and a suitable index on the column/s you are using in the WHERE clause of your SELECT you shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: How do you know which rows are popular? If most of the stored data never gets queried, then why do you store them in the first place?

Comment: If data is not deleted from the table, then inserts will not block selects, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/concurrent-inserts.html

Comment: I have primary key char(32) - hash of file. I store all data, becouse it is 0,0001% chance to read rare row.

Comment: I ask you again: how do you know which records will be popular and which not? If you cannot tell, it is impossible to move those data out of your table. You can optimise data storage and query using merge table engine or table partitioning.

Comment: Yes a know which records are popular.

Answer (score 0):

Use a cronjob to `INSERT...SELECT` and `DELETE` inactive rows in your table to another table, if you have a way to locate those inactive rows, e.g. if those rows have a certain range of timestamp. That gives you the ability to find out those rows while not affecting the performance of most other queries.

Comment: Why to another schema?

Comment: So when queries are run on the original schema, it would not need to seek through the bulky table. Or is this my wrong understanding?

Comment: 1. We have no idea, if these rows can be identified at all. 2. Even if you can identify such rows, how do you propose to differenciate in advance if a query needs only the table with the popular records or the table holding the inactive ones are also needed? 3. You do not need to move them to a different schema, just to a different table.